Настройка MSSQL в WildFly (Failed TestConnection )
Пытаюсь настроить mssql в wildfly
Скачал и установил:

MSSQL Server 2016 SP2 (экземпляр mssqlserver, бд создал, адрес=DESKTOP-XXX)
JDBC (mssql-jdbc-12.8.1.jre11)
WildFly 34.0.1.Final
JDK 23

Настройка mssql:

в менеджере mssql вкл. стек TCP/IP, port=1433

Настройка java:

создал переменную JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-23
прописал переменную JAVA_HOME в Path = %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Настройки wildfly:

создал пользователя через add-user.bat (role = superuser)
создал каталог ...\wildfly-34.0.1.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\microsoft\sqlserver\jdbc\main
в созданный каталог положил mssql-jdbc-12.8.1.jre11.jar + создал файлик module.xml с телом


    <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc">
        <resources>
            <resource-root path="mssql-jdbc-12.8.1.jre11.jar"/>
        </resources>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.api"/> 
            <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
            <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
        </dependencies>
    </module>



в файле ...\wildfly-34.0.1.Final\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml прописал


    <driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc">
      <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>


Запускаю ...\wildfly-34.0.1.Final\bin\standalone.xml, захожу
Вижу jdbc

Добавляю datasource XA:

Microsoft SQLServer
JNDI Name = java:/MSSQLXADS
Driver Name = sqlserver
Driver XA Datasource Class = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource
Value = ServerName=DESKTOP-XXX
User Name = user_db, Password = psw_user_db
Выполняю тест коннектора, возвращает ошибку


В чем проблема? где ошибся? как пофиксить))?

исправьте, пожалуйста, заголовок, чтобы он отражал краткую суть проблемы.

Укажите ресурс, который вы используете для настройки wildfly.
